# Required Documents for a UK visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I am an Indian student studying in germany and also doing part time work. I want to apply for UK visiting visa for a short period. Can i know what all documents i need to submit?

Comment: While we welcome you to this site, those who ask questions are expected to have done some research on their own. If you look at the [UK Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) site, it provides all the info and details, [including all documentation](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents)

Answer (score 1):

The UK authorities have produced a document, [Visit visa: guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents), that addresses this exact question.

While the only strictly required documents are your application and travel document, section 2 lists documents you'll almost certainly need to provide for a successful application, such as financial statements and proof of employment/studies.

Be sure to see section 4, "documents you should not send unless specifically requested," which lists a variety of documents they don't care about and aren't looking to see.